# Lookup option code at the time of the signal

Tags: programming

I'm trying to adapt the code below in Multicharts .NET version to accomplish the following task:

Calculate, at the time of the signal, the correct option code for a call option that has the least number of days to expiration and is closest to, but not higher than .90 delta. Then, use that calculated value in the trade.

The documentation on this platform is here https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=multicharts but I am not finding what I need to do to make this happen.

[code]namespace PowerLanguage.Strategy
{
    [IOGMode(IOGMode.Disabled)]
    public class Key_Reversal_LE_data2 : SignalObject
    {
        private IOrderMarket m_KeyRevLE;

```
    public Key_Reversal_LE_data2(object ctx) :
        base(ctx)
    {
        Length = 1;
    }

    [Input]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    protected override void Create(){
        m_KeyRevLE =
            OrderCreator.MarketNextBar(new SOrderParameters(Contracts.Default, "KeyRevLE", EOrderAction.Buy));
    }

    protected override void CalcBar(){
        if (PublicFunctions.DoubleLess(BarsOfData(2).Low[0], BarsOfData(2).Low.Lowest(Length, 1))
            && PublicFunctions.DoubleGreater(BarsOfData(2).Close[0], BarsOfData(2).Close[1]))
          m_KeyRevLE.Send();
    }
}
```

}[/code]